# I am trying to use validation to select relevant value from table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two forms frm_Rent and frm_Buy with same record source table tbl_Property which has 3 columns Col1, Col2, Col3. Col2 is alpha numeric and col3 is letters. How can i use Col3 to validate Col2 entry in frm_Rent and frm_Buy?

TBL_Property

Col1    Col2    Col3
1   300b    Rent
2   300G    Rent
3   300V    Buy
4   300F    Rent
5   300A    Both
6   300Z    Buy

When col2 and col3 of tbl_Property are updated, I need user(s) to be able to select whichever value from col2 is applicable to the form being used, such as when using frm_Rent users can ONLY select 300B, 300G 300F and 300A, and for frm_Buy user(s) can pick ONLY 300V, 300Z and 300A from col2 they will be restricted only to the values related to each form in col3, and both forms must be able to use the value of col3 designated as "Both".

I created a query Q_Property and used the Lookup function of the table tbl_Property. But I could only use it for just one form frm_Rent. I need to be able to use it for both forms.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

In frm_Rent set the recordsource for the Col2 combobox as:

```
SELECT Col2 FROM TBL_Property WHERE Col3<>"Buy"
```

And in frm_Buy:

```
SELECT Col2 FROM TBL_Property WHERE Col3<>"Rent"
```

**P.S:**
Add a new table for DealType as: DealTypeID (integer), DealType (text) and fill it as:
| DealTypeID | DealType |
| ---------- | -------- |
|    1       | Buy      |
|    2       | Rent     |
|    3       | Both     |

and use DealTypeID as Col3.